# How does this code work? What tells it to stop printing after the third row? Can someone break it down for me, in the most dumbed down way possible?

Tags: python-3.x, matrix

```
import random

def main():
    printMatrix(3)
```

## i don't understand how this code stops after the third row

```
def printMatrix(n):
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        for j in range(1, n + 1):
            print(random.randint(0, 1), end = " ")

        print()

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

range(1,n+1) is a builtin that returns [1, 2, 3], so iterating over range(1, n+1) is the same as iterating over [1, 2, 3] - each for loop body executes three times before terminating. The inner one prints your entries horizontally and the outer one causes the inner one to execute three times.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly this is a little basic, if you have trouble here I think anybody would suggest that you fetch a drink, get comfortable, open a book and start learning properly.

That said, I'll play:

- The first `for` construct is responsible for (1) iterating the columns and (2) breaking the line. It does all these things once for each value of `i` in the range 1..4 (where 4 comes from n+1 with n=3). Hence, you already have your answer: it iterates three times and thus (2) happens three times.
- To do (1), it uses another `for` construct, which is completely independent.
- To do (2), it uses `print()`.